# What's wrong with my update_post_meta function?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

When I save an acf post, I want to grab an ACF user field called contrib-id for the current user, and save it into a relationship field called contrib-meme. This is giving me a syntax error. What am I missing?

```
function my_acf_save_post($post_id)
    {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'contrib-meme', (get_user_meta ( get_current_user_id() ), $key = 'contrib-id', $single = true )) ;
    }
}    

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');
```

Comment: Include the stack trace in your question

Comment: Have a look at the answer. Its working fine in my local WP. Thanks

Comment: Well done @AlwaysHelping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
function my_acf_save_post($post_id){

            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'contrib-meme', get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'contrib-id', true ));

            }
        }    

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');
```

Hope this helps